# How to set a default value when using Object.keys in an ngFor loop?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<mat-select required formControlName="country" [(ngModel)]="defaultCountry" placeholder="Country">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(countryList)" [value]="[key]">{{[key]}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I have the above code. The countries are displayed fine in the Material Select, but the default option "DefaultCountry" is not working. I believe this is due to me using Object.keys because the following code does work with the default option.

```
<mat-select required formControlName="country" [(ngModel)]="defaultCountry" placeholder="Country">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let country of deleteLaterCountryList" [value]="country.countryCode">{{country.countryCode}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I want to know how I can make my first piece of code work using the default option. I don't want to use the second piece of code.

Comment: Please provide more code & context to it. We don't even know the structure of your list. Consider providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really need more details here, but I can see that you are using Reactive Form. In that case, there is no need for `ngModel`. Let us assume that you are using a `formGroup` called 'yourForm'.

```
<form [formGroup]="yourForm">
  .
  .
  <mat-select required formControlName="country" placeholder="Country">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(countryList)" [value]="[key]">{{[key]}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  .
  .
<form>
```

On the component.ts, you can use patchValue to assign a value to `country` formControl, which will be displayed as a default option.

```
yourForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  country: [null, Validators.required],
  .
  .
  // other form controls
});

ngOnInit() {
  this.yourForm.patchValue({
    country: 'SG'
  });
}
```